# Using Postman to take values from two different responses to assert against each other

Tags: json, automated-tests, postman

I have a test to run in Postman where I would like to assert two sets of arrays against each other. The data from each array will come from separate responses.

So I'm thinking I would make a call to get my expected results and in the Tests of that response I would set them in a variable and then I would use that variable in the Tests section of the next response to assert against. My problems are how to store the two arrays into variables from the JSON responses. They are in different formats.

Here is my expected results response. Here I need to set a variable to grab all the 'name' valules so I am expecting my variable to hold `[4],[FX01 - Yandi],[FX03 - Whaleback]`.

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "4",
        "description": "44"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "FX01 - Yandi",
        "description": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "FX03 - Whaleback",
        "description": ""
    },
]
```

And here is my actual result response where I would like to grab all 'name' values under the "sites" element so again I would expect to see an array of `[4],[FX01 - Yandi],[FX03 - Whaleback]` to match the earlier array for me to then assert against.

```
{
    "sites": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "4",
            "description": "44"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "FX01 - Yandi",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "FX03 - Whaleback",
            "description": ""
        },
    ],
    "shutdownTypes": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Major",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Minor",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "vc",
            "description": "vcvcx"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "vcc",
            "description": "vcxe33&*(&*^%$#\":}{><?/"
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first request test, get required elements and push it to array and set that array into environment variable.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var array = [];

jsonData.forEach(function(element) {
  array.push(element.name);
});

pm.environment.set("pre_request_array", array);
```

In your second request test, get environment variable we previously set and now can compare the both:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var currArray = [];

var prevArray = pm.environment.get("pre_request_array");

jsonData.sites.forEach(function(element) {
  currArray.push(element.name);
});

console.log(prevArray);
console.log(currArray);

//TODO: add compare logic here
```

In console, you can find output as below screen.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Worked a treat. I'm starting to get this although small pieces at a time. Is there any reference material you'd recommend specifically for grabbing elements from JSON to use in tests? I've struggled to find guides for this kind of thing.

Comment: Glad I could help you! I think there is no specific material *for grabbing elements from JSON *, it's just JavaScript that we're playing with, so you can google it every-time. I usually print console log and check the type of data I'm receiving, then dig at lower element that I wanted.